# Конвертация Tensorflow в IR, не видит библиотеку tensorflow

Tags: python, pip, openvino

Есть `.pb`-файл с моделью tensorflow. Пытаюсь её преобразовать в IR формат (для работы OpenVINO), вызываю команду:

```
mo_tf.py --input_model my_model.pb
```

и получаю ошибку:

```
[ ERROR ]
Detected not satisfied dependencies:
        tensorflow: not installed, required: 1.2.0
```

При этом ранее я запускал `install_prerequisites\install_prerequisites_tf.bat`, который должен был установить все необходимые зависимости, и он в логе показал, что всё успешно установлено.

Также я попытался установить tensorflow вручную:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

и в логе было указано, что tensorflow уже установлен.

По-видимому pip видит установленный tensorflow, а скрипт конвертера нет. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: @Harry , почему метка c++ не нужна? Библиотека OpenVINO то как раз для с++ и создана...

Comment: Ну, я не вижу здесь **ничего**, что касалось бы вопроса **программирования** на С++. Все относится только к python. Каким боком с С++ связано то, что pip видит, а скрипт конвертера нет? Так, утрируя, можно прицепить тег С++ просто к Python, если интерпретатор написан на С++ :)

Comment: Согласен... На вопрос вполне можно ответить, не зная плюсов вообще. Проверю другие вопросы по OpenVINO, я мог там тоже тэг просто так прицепить, не подумав.

Comment: Обычно в таких случаях проблема в нескольких версиях питона, установленных на машине, и в версии питона, к которой ведет дефолтный алиас `pip`. Выдай в терминале `pip --version` и `python --version`/`python -m site` (плюс еще зайди в `mo_tf.py` и посмотри, какая команда у тебя в шебэнге - если там, допустим, стоит `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, то проверяй `python3 --version` и т.д.). Если есть несоответствие, то ищи правильный экзешник пипа (допустим, `pip3`, `pip3.6` или вообще забандленный `python -m pip`) и устанавливай `tensorflow` для той версии питона, с которой будешь запускать свой скрипт.

Comment: BTW я бы и теги `нейронные-сети` и `openvino` убрал, тут лучше тег `pip` подойдет.

Comment: @hoefling , про нейронные сети согласен, убрал, а openvino - таких вопросов пока не так много, а эта проблема одна из тех, с которой столкнётся новичок в openvino, так что мне кажется лучше пока оставить...